# How to transition from one chapter to another?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have a webview. Everytime the user clicks on the next button, I load the webview with new content:

```
 webView.loadHTMLString(bodyText, baseURL: nil)
```

How do I create the following transition so that it seems like a new page is coming in from the right whenever a user clicks next?

See link for example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhbBo.jpg

Here's what I have so far

```
let webViewToRemove = webView
let webViewToAdd = WKWebView()
webViewToAdd.frame = webViewToRemove?.frame as! CGRect
if (swipeLeft) {
    webViewToAdd.center = CGPoint(x: 2.0*self.view.bounds.width, y: webView.bounds.midY)
} else {
    webViewToAdd.center = CGPoint(x: -2.0*self.view.bounds.width, y: webView.bounds.midY)
}
webView = webViewToAdd
webView.loadHTMLString(bodyText, baseURL: nil)
self.view.addSubview(webViewToAdd)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    if (swipeLeft) {
        webViewToRemove?.center = CGPoint(x: -2.0*self.view.bounds.width, y: self.webView.bounds.midY)
    } else {
        webViewToRemove?.center = CGPoint(x: 2.0*self.view.bounds.width, y: self.webView.bounds.midY)
    }
    webViewToAdd.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.webView.bounds.midY)
    }, completion: { finished in
        webViewToRemove?.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

Comment: I have an app that behaves just as you describe, to let the user navigate thru its Help pages. I use a UIPageViewController. Makes the view sliding trivial.

Comment: Hi Matt, would I put the webview inside the UIPageViewController @matt

Comment: You would wrap the web view in a view controller. The pages of a page view controller are view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app on the app store that behaves much as you seem to be describing. It shows its Help as web views loaded from html strings, just like what you are doing. The user can navigate right and left either with arrow buttons (top left) or by sliding manually with a finger. This screencast shows both; first I use the arrow buttons, then I slide manually:

[image]

How is that done? It's trivial; it's a UIPageViewController. No need to reinvent a wheel that Apple has already handed us.

Comment: Can you show me some code? How do you have the webview inside the UIPageViewController

Comment: Also how do you keep the header at the top. Can you show me some code?